# Installation failed [@adonisjs/validator]

Tags: npm, adonisjs, adonis-4

Quiero instalar @adonisjs/validator en mi proyecto de adonis, con el comando:

> adonis install @adonisjs/validator

pero me marca este error

[1/1] ❌  Installation failed [@adonisjs/validator]

```
ERROR  Command failed: npm i --save @adonisjs/validator
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: adonis-api-app@4.1.0
npm ERR! Found: @adonisjs/bodyparser@2.0.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@adonisjs/bodyparser
npm ERR!   @adonisjs/bodyparser@"~2.0.9" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @adonisjs/bodyparser@"^7.0.0" from @adonisjs/validator@11.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@adonisjs/validator
npm ERR!   @adonisjs/validator@"^11.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\juanv\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\juanv\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-30T04_38_03_282Z-debug.log
```

despues ejecute este comando:

> npm i --save @adonisjs/validator

y me marco otro error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: adonis-api-app@4.1.0
npm ERR! Found: @adonisjs/bodyparser@2.0.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@adonisjs/bodyparser
npm ERR!   @adonisjs/bodyparser@"~2.0.9" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @adonisjs/bodyparser@"^7.0.0" from @adonisjs/validator@11.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@adonisjs/validator
npm ERR!   @adonisjs/validator@"^11.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\juanv\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\juanv\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-30T04_40_33_919Z-debug.log
```

intente crean un nuevo proyecto y solo instalar @adonisjs/validator, pero me resulta el mismo error, ya borre cache con el comando:

> npm cache clean --force

y borre la carpeta node_modules y volvi a instalar las dependencias con:

> npm install --save

pero sigue marcandome el mismo error, graciasss

Comment: Utilizo la versión 4.1.0

Comment: Ah perfecto, Muchas gracias.

Comment: Sii muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los paquetes para la versión 4.x acaban de recibir una actualización y ahora debes agregar *legacy* para su descarga.

Entonces escribe tu comando de esta forma:

```
npm i @adonisjs/validator@legacy
```

Enlaces de interés:

- [Información sobre el tiempo de vida de los paquetes para versiones inferiores a Adonis 5](https://github.com/adonisjs/core/discussions/2416)
- [Actualización de paquetes para Adonis 4.1](https://github.com/adonisjs/core/discussions/2466)